# How to save a custom structure to disk?

Tags: swift, struct, save

In my project I create a custom structure I want to save to disk. I know I can use NSUserDefaults or an NSArchiver. But how to to that with a structure? I can only find solutions for classes. The properties of that structure are Strings, CLLocationCoordinate2D, [CIFaceFeature] and Data(PNG file of UIImage).

Comment: Make it a class that conforms to NSCoding and use KeyedArchiever to save the object data to a file

Comment: I would like to stick with a structure here. Is that also possible?

Comment: Ok, I will do but isn't it right normally to use a structure at this point?

Comment: If you need it to persist make it a class otherwise a struct is fine

Comment: You can generate a dictionary from the struct and archive that. However, `CIFaceFeature` is NOT archivable as it doesn't confirm to `NSCoding`